# Why use two stars in point cut expression to match return type?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

In book Spring in Action, I found following AspectJ point cut expression:

```
@Pointcut("execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..))")
void performance();
```

This will designate point cut **performance** to include methods whose name is "perform" and whose return type can be any. But notice it uses two stars (**) to match the return type, as I've experimented, one star (*) can perfectly do the job, this means the following line can do the same thing:

```
 @Pointcut("execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))")
 void performance();
```

And I noticed that many AspectJ demos use two stars (**) to match "any return type", so is there some reason to do so? What is the problem of using one star to match "any return type"?

Comment: I was reading the same book and it makes no explanations about this. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) helps understand this better. It says

> Spring AOP users are likely to use the execution pointcut designator the most often. The format of an execution expression is:

```
execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern declaring-type-pattern?name-pattern(param-pattern) throws-pattern?)
```

The first part `modifiers-pattern` is optional as you can see it has suffixed with `?`. This is to designate method's access type.

So in your case, pointcut expression `execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..))` advises execution of methods with any access modifier and any return type on the type `concert.Performance` with method name `perform` that has any argument type.

`execution(* concert.Performance.perform(..))` means the same where the first `*` is optional that denotes `perform` method on the type `concert.Performance` that accepts any type of arguments and method may have any return type(with optional access modifier meaning that access modifier can be anything).